# Did Dumbledore have any Muggle friends?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, muggles

With all his affection towards Muggles for several decades, one may wonder if he even had any Muggle friends at all. He surely was acquainted with the parents of his Muggle-born students, but I'm curious if he had any actual friendship with a Muggle (where the Muggle knows that he is a wizard, and they spend time together fooling around etc).

Comment: I'm not answering this to Voldemort :P

Comment: A more depressing question - "Did Dumbledore have any friends?"

Comment: @DavidS I like to imagine him alone conversing with both Fawkes and his patronus.

Comment: @Voldemort Well, yes, you would like that, wouldn't you? You wouldn't want him to be *happy*.

Comment: @DavidS At least [one](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gellert_Grindelwald), but he turned out to be a psycho killer.

Comment: I can't remember any specific mention of friends, but there are definite signs of his affinity and familiarity with the Muggle community, such as his taste for sherbert lemons.

Answer (score 8):

**Probably Not.**

I can't find any canon on this, but he grew up in Godric's Hollow and then went to Hogwarts.  After that, he worked at Hogwarts for the rest of his life.  He's never lived in a Muggle community, and as a kid, he thought wizards to be superior to Muggles.  He has probably, as you said, met the parents of Muggle-born students at Hogwarts, but that is all he would have done, and they don't really count as his friends.  He had no chances to meet any Muggles during his lifetime.

Comment: Godric's Hollow was a mixed community; it had both magical and Muggle inhabitants. Considering his younger sister was traumatised after being attacked by local Muggle children it seems like a safe assumption that was the case when he was growing up.

Comment: Godric's Hollow is home for a lot of wizards, but there are muggles in there as well ["Do you know much about Hogsmeade? I've read
it's the only entirely non-Muggle settlement in Britain --" - Hermione, PoA, chp.05]. That said, the Dumbledores had an awful experience with muggles, and if we are to believe Aunt Muriel, his mother probably wouldn't aprove of him associating with muggles ("a terrifying woman, simply terrifying. Muggle-born, though I heard she pretended otherwise ").